# Sails.js change bodyParser for specific paths

Tags: sails.js, skipper

In Sails.js 0.10.5, I want to replace bodyParser for specific paths. For example, use a different body parser for path '/app/upload' and for the rest use the default. How do I do this?

Comment: Had a quick check but couldn't find anything - the docs here http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/middleware talk about how to add or override http middleware, as well as a section on including express middleware as a policy - suggest you ask on IRC channel #sailsjs on chat.freenode.net

Comment: @arcseldon Yea I couldn't find any answers. I had to make a switch to busboy to parse incoming requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overriding `config/http.js`. Add your custom parser to the middleware, and replace `bodyParser` in the order with your custom parser.

Something like this should work

```
module.exports.http = {
    middleware: {
        superBodyParser: function (req, res, next) {
            if (req.path === '/app/upload') {
                // your custom parser
            }
            else {
                require('skipper')(req, res, next);
            }
        },
        order: [
          'startRequestTimer',
          'cookieParser',
          'session',
          'myRequestLogger',
          // 'bodyParser',  <-- not required anymore
          'superBodyParser' 
          'handleBodyParserError',
          'compress',
          'methodOverride',
          'poweredBy',
          '$custom',
          'router',
          'www',
          'favicon',
          '404',
          '500'
        ]
    }
};
```